# Apache running but no response from server?

Tags: httpd

I've got a fresh Fedora 15 installation on my server that's been giving me trouble.

My first problem was that httpd wouldn't start. I kept getting an error that there was a segfault and the sysadmin eventually traced it back to a problem with mod_perl, so he removed it and httpd started fine.

I've had another very vexing problem recently, though: I get no response from Apache.

- I can SSH into my server
- I've got the right IP address
- It pings
- The httpd service is up and running
- I've got an index.html file in the webroot
- If I wget XX.XXX.XXX.XXX (the server's IP address) when SSH'd into the server itself, I get a response

But whenever I make a request to the server from any computer, regardless of ISP, I get no response - Chrome says it can't even connect. I'm absolutely stumped about how to fix it, and I've bugged the sysadmin quite a bit already. My robotics team gets this server space free from a company and I like to bug the sysadmin as little as possible about this kind of thing, but I suppose I'll have to if this question doesn't turn up any solutions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the firewall is running on the server?  It is possible that it is an blocking external port 80/433 requests

Comment: Same here, but Opera connects just fine.  Same thing happens to vsftpd.  Chrome chokes but Opera does it just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall issue if wget works from the command line.

Temporarily disable the firewall using:

```
service iptables stop
```

If it works then you know you need to add a rule to your firewall to allow port 80 and or 443.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that solved it! How would I go about adding exceptions for a general purpose webserver doing FTP, HTTP, and the like?

Comment: This will tell you how - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-11-how-to-block-or-open-httpweb-service.html

Comment: Depends on if you have a GUI installed or not. Being you are using Fedora rather than CentOS I figure there may be a chance you do. If you have the tool available and are running on a graphical dekstop using system-config-firewall may be easier.  Do not go back and forth between command line and system-config-firewall though because one will overwrite the other.

Comment: I don't have a GUI, no. Really not too much need for one, although I could see how it could come in handy to simplify things.

Comment: Awesome, allowing port 80 and 443 solved the problem

Comment: I had this issue on an AWS EC2 server I created, and the fix was to enable access for HTTP and HTTPS from the security group assigned to the EC2 instance. (I always forget to do that!)

Answer (score 5):

On CentOS 7 or similar, check if you're running firewalld:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

Ubuntu has [ufw](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-firewall) which is a friendlier interface to `iptables`. See `man ufw` for details.

If you see the service running, you can open port 80 by adding the `http` service as explained by [root users](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-centos-7-with-firewalld/):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Incidentally, I once installed CentOS 7 minimal on a machine and the firewall was not installed by default. But using another ISO on another machine, it was installed on its own. And I kept checking on the wrong one, which told me that there was no firewall!

A useful command that will tell you that it's definitely the firewall is nmap:

```
sudo nmap -sS -O -p80 ip-address

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-11 15:56 IST
Nmap scan report for ip-address
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

If you see *filtered* instead of *open*, there's no doubt a firewall. Double check you're in the right machine if you have several terminals open!

Another quick way to check from the terminal is to use curl. On the server:

```
curl localhost
```

That should return the homepage. On another machine on the network:

```
curl 1.2.3.4     # use the actual host's IP address
```

That should also return the homepage. If you have to press CTRL+C because it sits waiting, or if you get an error like `Failed to connect to 1.2.3.4 port 80: No route to host` but got a response when you did it locally, it's a clear sign that something, most likely a firewall, is blocking access.