# iptables configuration?

Tags: iptables

This is related to my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/319318/apache-running-but-no-response-from-server). Not really a need to read it, but I'm running a Fedora 15 webserver and I've been trying to get Apache running correctly.

I've got an incorrectly configured firewall for a webserver at the moment - it's blocking inbound requests on port 80. I found it was a problem with iptables, so ran a command to correct it:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

That didn't do anything. Both before and after I restarted the iptables service, I got no response from the server.

The next suggestion on [the page I'm using to fix this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-11-how-to-block-or-open-httpweb-service.html) is to append these lines to /etc/system/iptables, so I tried that:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

But iptables wouldn't even start after I added these lines. so I changed them to look more like the rest of my config file. So now the file in its entirety looks like this:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited


-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT


-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

The lines I added are the ones separated in the middle.
Alas, this didn't work either. And I am making sure to restart the iptables service after each thing I try.

So, how could I fix this to allow my webserver to act correctly, being able to serve websites on port 80 (and 443)? I do need to leave iptables enabled, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you deny all traffic in the line before your addition, this is the cause. Move the line behind your edit (or vice versa) and it will probably work.

And then a tip: Playing with firewalls on a live system to learn is a bad idea.

Comment: unless you have serial console access to the system :-)

Comment: or unless you have a cron job that flushes the rules regularly.

Comment: Flushing the rules is not completely reliable since the chain policies will still be intact. I've already been bitten by this technique.

Comment: @Alpha01 Good point. But it only should point out an alternative.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why is it such a terrible idea?
And what exactly does it mean to flush the rules? And what are chain policies?
Obviously I'm no sysadmin, I tend to stay in the frontend. I am a Linux enthusiast, though, so I know my way around reasonably well. Oh, and it worked, by the way. Thanks!

Comment: @TreyK Forgive me for being short here. But these are basic questions. A good book about netfilter/ipchains or a tutorial/howto about the same topic should shed some light upon it.

Comment: @maliq A true statement, fair enough! Thanks, regardless.

Comment: @TreK Ok, then a helpful link from me: http://www.frozentux.net/documents/iptables-tutorial/ And note the iptables is the first defense line (ok, second) in your security concept. So one should know what to do or otherwise your security is only "apparent security".

Comment: If you're feeling to lazy to read. Linux Journal made some really great videos on iptables. [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldB8kDEtTZA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldB8kDEtTZA)

Comment: Flush the rules mean to scrap all modifications to the rules u add previusly (to permit the access over the net with ssh for example before an mistake). Play with live system means u have to kill them (like smashing whit an axe or so. jiggles XD).

Comment: @mailq serial console, with bios redirection.... and then iptables -F && ip link set eth0 down is fun and easy .... and gives you time to investigate intrusion

Comment: for our purposes, ...u prob want this run every hour... if !procrunning(sshd,2222); do sshd -f sshd.emerg.conf ;fi